# Why did Emma remember Jessica while others did not?

Tags: plot-explanation, timeless

In *The Miracle of Christmas*, the two-part finale of *Timeless*, Emma Whitmore asks for Jessica, but the other person in Rittenhouse doesn’t remember her. Because of that, Emma realizes that history was altered, and confirms that when she checks the vault and sees that the gold Jessica placed there was missing.

Given that she wasn’t time traveling, why did Emma remember Jessica while others did not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look again, the scene is taken such that,

*Emma is walking away from the mothership calling for Jessica*

[image]

which explains that she *must have been time travelling* and just got out of the mothership.